# DispatcherTimer with Window.Close causing crash

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am writing a C# app that has a main window and a separate login window.  I set a DispatcherTimer to open a new login window if the user is idle for a certain period of time.

My app is crashing when i call .Close() on the login window.  However, if I remove the DispatcherTimer code it works fine.  Is System.Timers.Timer a better choice for this or is there something else I maybe doing wrong?

The strange part is the app doesn't crash and works fine when I run it in Visual Studio, but crashes when i Install it then run it.

Thanks,

Matt

Edit:  I just tried installing it on my machine it works fine, but will break when installed on a client machine.  Not sure why this would happen.. Maybe a missing dependency in the setup project?  Thanks for your posts guys.

Comment: Do you have any info from the crash, like a stack trace or anything?

Comment: Try to create a minimal repro test case and post it.

Comment: Yes the window is modal.

Comment: I just tried installing it on my machine it works fine, but will break when installed on a client machine. Not sure why this would happen.. Maybe a missing dependency? Thanks for your posts guys.

Comment: Are you able to determine exactly when it crashes?  IE. does it crash when the window is opened, after it opens, when it's closing?  It's a little cheap but you might resort to writing to a log (text file) just to try and track where the crash is actually occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking on all thrown exceptions may allow you to get a call stack for the problem.  Go to  "Exceptions..." in the Debug menu, and check all of the checkboxes in the "thrown" column.

You will probably want to undo this after you are done testing because it will break even on exceptions handled correctly by the application.

Comment: This is the right way to address this issue. There could be many things that went wrong, and the only way to find out is to break and investigate the exception as it is being thrown. In my situation, I was creating the `DispatcherTimer` in an `async` method after `await`, which means that it ran on a different thread.